# How to change checkbox background color with white color around

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm looking a solution how to change css background color with padding or white color around the checkbox, I tried and play around using margin, padding height and etc, but no luck.
So when user click the checkbox, it would show background color, it's working, but I'd like to have white padding around the checkbox, is it possible?

```css
.checkbox {
  margin: 0 0 1em 2em;
}
.checkbox .tag {
  color: #595959;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
}
.checkbox label {
  display: inline;
}
.checkbox .input-assumpte {
  display: none;
}
.input-assumpte + label:after {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid #cacece;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05),
    inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  display: inline-block;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  content: "";
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.input-assumpte:checked + label:after {
  background-color: #0e4caa;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" class="input-assumpte" id="input-confidencial" />
       <label for="input-confidencial">Confidencial</label>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly what you want is [background-clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip), easy:

```css
.checkbox {
    margin: 0 0 1em 2em;
}

.checkbox .tag {
    color: #595959;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
}

.checkbox label {
    display: inline;
}

.checkbox .input-assumpte {
    display: none;
}

.input-assumpte + label::after {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border: 4px solid #0e4caa;
    background-clip: content-box;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    display: inline-block;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    content: "";
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.input-assumpte:checked + label::after {
    background-color: #0e4caa;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="input-assumpte" id="input-confidencial" />
    <label for="input-confidencial">Confidencial</label>
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hqfw62n3/1/).

> The background-clip CSS property sets whether an element's background
>   extends underneath its border box, padding box, or content box.

Just to mention, there is also one more solution for extra border using `outline`, but it extends the element:

```css
.checkbox {
    margin: 0 0 1em 2em;
}

.checkbox .tag {
    color: #595959;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
}

.checkbox label {
    display: inline;
}

.checkbox .input-assumpte {
    display: none;
}

.input-assumpte + label::after {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border: 4px solid #fafafa;
 outline: 4px solid #0e4caa;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    display: inline-block;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    content: "";
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.input-assumpte:checked + label::after {
    background-color: #0e4caa;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="input-assumpte" id="input-confidencial" />
    <label for="input-confidencial">Confidencial</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS `box-shadow` property:

```css
.checkbox {
  margin: 0 0 1em 2em;
}

.checkbox .tag {
  color: #595959;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
}

.checkbox label {
  display: inline;
}

.checkbox .input-assumpte {
  display: none;
}

.input-assumpte+label:after {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid #cacece;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  display: inline-block;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  content: "";
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.input-assumpte:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #0e4caa;
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 4px white
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="input-assumpte" id="input-confidencial" />
  <label for="input-confidencial">Confidencial</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

inset shadow should be sufficient for this

```
box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05),
    inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 0 0 0 2px #0e4caa ,inset  0 0 0 4px white;
```

Demo

```css
.checkbox {
  margin: 0 0 1em 2em;
}

.checkbox .tag {
  color: #595959;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
}

.checkbox label {}

.checkbox .input-assumpte {
  display: none;
}

.input-assumpte+label:after {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid #cacece;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  display: inline-block;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  content: "";
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.input-assumpte:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #0e4caa;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 0 0 0 2px #0e4caa, inset 0 0 0 4px white;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="input-assumpte" id="input-confidencial" />
  <label for="input-confidencial">Confidencial</label>
</div>
```

outline with a negative offset could also work:

```
  outline: solid white 2px;
  outline-offset: -5px;
```

```css
.checkbox {
  margin: 0 0 1em 2em;
}

.checkbox .tag {
  color: #595959;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
}

.checkbox label {}

.checkbox .input-assumpte {
  display: none;
}

.input-assumpte+label:after {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid #cacece;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  display: inline-block;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  content: "";
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.input-assumpte:checked+label:after {
  background-color: #0e4caa;
  outline: solid white 2px;
  outline-offset: -5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="input-assumpte" id="input-confidencial" />
  <label for="input-confidencial">Confidencial</label>
</div>
```